# EXTJS4 - For TreeStore, how to pass parameters and action methods?

Tags: javascript, tree, store, extjs4

I am using Extjs4 TreeStore, i want to know how to pass parameters (like mode = 'list') and action methods (POST or GET).

Thanks in advance.

EXTJS 3.x i have used like this it's working fine:

```
loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
    dataUrl: 'content/permissions/server.php',
    baseParams: {
        mode: 'getPermissions'
    }
})
```

EXTJS 4.x i have used like this but it is not working:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'server.php'
    },
    extraParams: {
        mode: 'getTree'
    },
    actionMethods: 'POST',
    root: {
        text: 'Tree',
        id: 'src',
        expanded: true
    }
});
```

Thanks,
Riyaz

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This the correct one

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'server.php',
        extraParams: {
            mode: 'getTree'
        },
        actionMethods: 'POST'
    },
    root: {
        text: 'Tree',
        id: 'src',
        expanded: true
    }
});
```

Comment: @Riyaz **No, you are wrong.** [actionMethod](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Ajax2.html#Ext-data-proxy-Ajax-property-actionMethods) is an object and not a string. In your case [getMethod](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Ajax2.html#Ext-data-proxy-Ajax-method-getMethod) evaluates to `undefined`, which causes `Ext.Ajax` to use the default request method `GET`. So the result is **exactly** my answer. You basically took my right answer, modified it in a wrong way and accepted it.

Answer (score 5):

You should carefully check your configuration parameters with the current [Ext JS 4 API Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.TreeStore).

What I see at first glance:

1. [actionMethods](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-property-actionMethods) is an object and not a string value configuration. It's implemented in both the AJAX and the REST proxies. If your need a full featured editable tree, consider a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) proxy. Only if you go beyond CRUD, you need to provide additional `actionMethods` to the REST proxy.
2. [extraParams](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server) belongs to the Proxy and not to the tree configuration.

So your store configuration should look like:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
  autoLoad: true,
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'server.php',
    extraParams: {
      mode: 'getTree'
    },
  },
  root: {
      text: 'Tree',
      id: 'src',
      expanded: true
  }
 });
```

Have you verified if at least an Ajax request has been sent to the server? You can easily check this with [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: Hi, It's working fine for the parameters (extraParams) what about the actionMethods POST and GET (eg: actionMethods: 'POST')

Answer (score 0):

example of correct setting:

```
  actionMethods: {
                destroy:'DELETE',
                create: 'POST',
                update: 'POST',
                read: 'GET'
            },
```